# Optimization on MCMC codes

Tags: monte-carlo, gpu, random-sampling, sample-statistics

I am looking for MCMC codes with a GPU suport (like NVIDIA or OpenCL libraries) to make faster run chains.

If someone could have a state of the art ...

Comment: For simulating a single Markov chain, there's generally little parallelism available in a Gibbs sampler.  However, if you want to simulate many chains in parallel, and you're willing to run these chains long enough to get through your burn-in period, then using a GPU may be worthwhile.

Comment: @BrianBorchers .Thans for your quick answer. Could you provide some links which explains how to run multiple chains (I have well undertsood) in parallel. The main issue is that a Markov-Chain is intrisically serial, so are there ways to circumvent this intrinsic property ?

Comment: You didn't say what platform you'd prefer to use. I know Python has some different methods, but I've not yet exploited any of them. You could try reading more about it [here](https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/MCMC.html) or [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.228.7272&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: @Kat . I have posted my MCMC code in my original question. Could you see at first sight the way to benefit from GPU to optimize this code ? Regards

Comment: @youpilat it looks like your original question was about libraries that could do this. Your recent edits seem like new question and should probably be posted separately (maybe with a link to this question for context).

Answer (score 1):

The Julia probabilistic programming libraries like [Turing.jl](https://turing.ml/stable/) work on abstract array types and use the [Julia automatic differentiation tooling](https://juliadiff.org/), so if you write your model as something that uses [CUDA.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl) then your evaluations will take place on the GPU. I've used this for large stiff PDE discretizations.

Comment: @ChrisRackaukas . Thanks for your answer. Could you take a look at my MCMC code that I would like to use with GPU.

Answer (score 0):

One like this one?

https://github.com/brandonckelly/CUDAHM

What exactly are you looking for, which language, how plug&play and for which kind of problem?

Depending on the case stuff like pyMC3 or tensorflow probability might already suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does mean "Routines for using CUDA to accelerate Bayesian inference of Hierarchical Models using Markov Chain Monte Carlo with GPUs.", I mean especially, the Hierarchical Models using MCMC ? I don't know this notion ? Moreover, Can I use this code with 6 or 7 or more parameters for example with CUDAHM ?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @HydroGuy . do pyMC3 or tensorflow support GPU for drawing or buid Markov chain) ? What is tensorflow exactly, I have heard it about don't understand its utility : is it a library like numpy ? Best regards

Comment: @youpilat13, Tensorflow is a library for machine learning, specially deep learning. The basic primitives of the library (tensors) are basically the same as numpy (ndarrays), but with a backend that supports GPU acceleration. On top of that the library allows you to define (GPU acceleration) operations on those tensors on the form of a graph. For example, regarding MCMC specifically: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/mcmc

Comment: @HydroGuy . Thanks for your quick answer. Could you take a look please at my MCMC code that I would like to use with GPU. How to include this code with CUDAHM or pyMC3 ? Regards

Answer (score 0):

The library that pymc uses to do this is aesara.

https://github.com/aesara-devs/aesara

Stan uses OpenCL

https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/articles/opencl.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. By the way, could you take a look at my MCMC code that I would like to use with GPU.